# After reseting Linksys router to the default settings I still can’t login to change settings

Tags: router

I have a Linksys WNR120N router that I forgot the Wi-Fi password to, and didn’t mind resetting to get it working again. After doing a factory reset by holding the red button, the router won’t let me log into its settings panel to change the Wi-Fi password from open to a password protected setup.

After hours of searching, I came up with the idea to try and pull an index of the page by using this Wget command:

```
wget 192.168.1.1 --user='' --password=admin
```

And it immediately outputted an `Index.html` file in the directory. I then entered `firefox index.html` and it showed a botched settings panel as if it did in fact connect!

When logging in by simply typing in the gateway IP to the address bar, it asks for a username and password. I leave user blank just like i did in the command, and type in `admin` without quotes into the password slot, but it just clears out and pops up the same login popup!

I still don't know how my shell can access it but FireFox can’t.

Also, I ran the Wget command on a Linux laptop, so please don’t give answers by installing.

P.S.: I even tried it on my phone and it did the same exact result, it disappears on enter and pops up the request again. I don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Hopefully a given, but make sure whatever device you're trying to connect to your router from is set up with an IP address on the same subnet as your router.

Comment: Darth Continent, how do I make sure they're on the same subnet through Bash, preferably?

Comment: I noticed a decent amount of 0 posts asking this same question, from 2014 to 2017. I wonder why no one has answered these issues?

Comment: So your question is about accessing the admin page after reseting the settings, correct? My best advice is to reset it again and possibly update the firmware via abc Ethernet connection. Also, did you see this: “[Attacks on Linksys Routers Trigger Mass Password Reset](https://threatpost.com/attacks-on-linksys-routers-trigger-mass-password-reset/154914/)”

Comment: Try this:
1. Use an ethernet cable to connect and disable the wifi on your computer.
2. Use microsoft edge to connect instead of Firefox.
3. Try resetting the router again by waiting +30 seconds of what you waited before.
4. Shut down the router from the power supply and wait 2 minutes before you turn it back on.
5. Try using admin for the username and admin for the password. The error you are getting suggests the username or password is incorrect.

Comment: CFCBazar keep in mind I am using Firefox because I use Linux, so MsEdge is not really an option for me. I will try using an alternative, in fact multiple alternatives. JakeGould, I haven't connected this linksys router to a single byte of internet in the past year so I can confirm this is not an attack on my router. did you share that suggesting I attack my own router in attempt to gain access to the settings? if so, I will add that to what I can try to fix this thing.

Comment: blank username + "admin" password > fail
"admin" username + "admin" password > fail
"admin" U + "password" P > fail
blank U + blank P > fail
any other combinations I can try? keep in mind Wget managed to show the settings page in a broken HTML output, so it is not firmware (hopefully), and it is not hackers (very much hopefully), so all that's left to try is more resetting, and trying different browsers like Pale Moon and... possibly Chrome. *edit: what is an "abc ethernet connection", quote by JakeGould